# Oracle PL/SQL: how to delete a row and then output it using pipe?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dml

I have a package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_location IS
    TYPE dep_row IS RECORD (id departments.department_id%TYPE, name departments.department_name%TYPE);
    TYPE dep_table IS TABLE OF dep_row;
    FUNCTION drop_departments (v_city_title IN VARCHAR2) RETURN dep_table PIPELINED;
END pkg_location;
```

I need to implement `drop_departments` function, which deletes rows from the `departments` table by `city` and outputs deleted departments' data using pipes.

But I really don't know where to start from. Can you please help me?

Table structure:

```
DEPARTMENTS: DEPARTMENT_ID (NUMBER) | DEPARTMENT_NAME (VARCHAR 40) | LOCATION_ID (NUMBER)
LOCATIONS:   LOCATION_ID (NUMBER)   | CITY (VARCHAR 40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need 3 steps:

- save all records that are going to be deleted into local table that has same type as function
- delete the records
- return the collection that you saved (and it's not necessary should be pipelined)

there's a problem with pipeline function - you cannot select * from table(my_pipe_function) and make delete (DML) operation inside the function during select.

to avoid the issue with delete inside function you need change logic and don't use pipeline OR you need delete records in `autonomous transaction`

see 3 samples below

```
insert into departments(id , department_id , department_name , city_title ) values(1, 1, '1', 'City-1');
insert into departments(id , department_id , department_name , city_title )  values(2, 2, '2', 'City-1');
insert into departments(id , department_id , department_name , city_title )  values(3, 2, '3', 'City-2');
```

sample 1 with `pipeline`

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_location IS
    FUNCTION drop_departments (v_city_title IN VARCHAR2) RETURN dep_table PIPELINED
    is
      tblResult dep_table;
    begin

      --delete the records and save deleted records
      delete from departments 
              where city_title = v_city_title
      RETURNING department_id, department_name 
      BULK COLLECT INTO tblResult;

      --return list of deleted records        
      for i in tblResult.FIRST .. tblResult.LAST loop
        pipe row (tblResult(i));
      end loop;
    end;
END pkg_location;
```

but then you cannot use smth like this
`select * from table( pkg_location.drop_departments('City-1'))`

sample 2 - I removed pipelined

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_location IS
    FUNCTION drop_departments (v_city_title IN VARCHAR2) RETURN dep_table 
    is
      tblResult dep_table;
    begin

      --delete the records and save deleted records
      delete from departments 
              where city_title = v_city_title
        RETURNING department_id, department_name 
        BULK COLLECT INTO tblResult;

      --return list of deleted records        
      return tblResult;
  end;      
END pkg_location;
```

and now you can use the function this way:

```
declare
  tbl pkg_location.dep_table;
begin
  tbl := pkg_location.drop_departments('City-1');

  for i in tbl.first .. tbl.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(tbl(i).name);
  end loop;
end;
```

output will be 1 and 2

sample 3 - using `autonomous transactions`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_location IS

    FUNCTION drop_departments (v_city_title IN VARCHAR2) RETURN dep_table PIPELINED    
    is
    --it let you use the function in select * from table(f)
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      tblResult dep_table;
    begin
      --delete the records and save deleted records
      delete from departments 
              where city_title = v_city_title
       returning department_id, department_name 
      bulk collect into tblResult;

      --you must do the commit before pipe row ()
      commit;

      --return list of deleted records        
      for i in tblResult.FIRST .. tblResult.LAST loop
        pipe row (tblResult(i));
      end loop;
    end;
END pkg_location;
```

now you can use

```
select * from table(pkg_location.drop_departments('City-1'))
```

result will be:

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

Comment: The selects before delete are unnecessary as well as potential concurrency problem. You can just output deleted records into collection using `DELETE departments WHERE city_title = v_city_title RETURNING department_id, department_name BULK COLLECT INTO tblResult;`

Comment: There is no problem with pipelined version, it can use autonomous transaction too. You only need to issue commit before PIPE ROW because this yields a value and leaves the function until next record is needed and an autonomous transaction must be committed/rolled back before the function scope is left.

Comment: But in this case the non-pipelined approach returning collection is the best. It's the least amount of code and you allocate memory for all the deleted records anyway so iterating and yielding the fixed collection doesn't make sense.